# I tried making a custom rectangle stencil but now its over anything

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, kivymd, stencils

I am trying to make a custom "image" in kivy/md and i cannot figure out why the shape is over anything i tried to put a "z=-1" it doesnt work, i don't know what should i do

```
<Screen4>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex("E8E8F9")
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .5
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 230/255, 230/255, 230/255, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 60, 60]
                    texture: Gradient.horizontal(get_color_from_hex("7A89FC"), get_color_from_hex("4d5AE0")) 
                StencilPush
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 60, 60]
                StencilUse
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex("8691F9")
                Ellipse:
                    pos: (-130, self.parent.height - 200)
                    size: (350, 350)
                    
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex("5F6BE3")
                Ellipse:
                    pos: (self.parent.width - 150, 400)
                    size: (350, 350)
                StencilUnUse
                StencilPop

        MDLabel:
            markup: True
            text: "Hello"
            font_name: "Poppins-Bold"
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {'y': .345,'x': .035}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: rgba(255, 255, 255)
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: "8dp"
            padding: "8dp"

            MDLabel:
                id: drawer_text
                text: ''
                font_style: "Subtitle1"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            MDLabel:
                id: drawer_email
                text: ''
                font_style: "Caption"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
.......................................................... rest of the code
```

When I remove the blue thing everything its in his place but when i put it it stands over anything but i want to put it there beacuse it looks cool, if you can make that design without roundedrectangles and anything ellse (more easily let me know)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0m0j.png)
[What I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wLFo.png)